# Implementing ICAL calendars jsf

Tags: jsf, icalendar

Im trying to implement ical calendars using java1.8/jsf2.2 in a way that makes embedding them into outlook possible:

[image: outlook add calendar dialog]

It be good if i could store generated calendars and update them automatically. I intend to pass the needed parameters in the url. Something like

`http://example.com/ical/calendars.ics?id=12&includeAll=1`

I found primefaces FileDownload but Im not sure that is what I need. Maybe some FileServlet? I stumbled upon omnifaces' FileServlet and figured since I have the omnifaces jar anyway I could try to use that. Or the old version of BalusC found here: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Would any of those approaches even work?

What Im thinking is storing generated calendars in a temp folder and update them dayly. Or, using a FileServlet, I could generate them on request. Im not sure how to go at it. Which of the suggested ways is the best? Or are all of them wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OmniFaces contains the mentioned FileServlet only from Version 2 onwards, which requires CDI, I wont be able to use it because I used Spring for DI. Otherwise that would have been the solution...

Using the BalusC's FileServlet I proposed in my question, I'm able to generate stuff on request.